# Reverse Routing in cakePHP 2

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.x

I have created URLs in cake 2.x using strings like

```
$this->Html->link('View', '/posts/view/' . $id)
//posts/view/id
```

in multiple times And then later decided that `/posts` should be called `/articles` instead in URL.

//articles/view/id

I don't want to change my existing code, I want to use Reverse Routing.

I read about the reverse routing but could not find any suitable example

related to my problem.

It will be appreciated if anybody gives me solution regarding my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Dont hard code the urls, use arrays instead

```
$this->Html->link('View', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view' ,$id));
```

And in your route file (app/Config/routes.php), specify the routing rule

```
//The indexaction
Router::connect(
    '/articles',
    array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index')
);


//The view action
Router::connect(
    '/articles/:id',
    array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view'),
    array(
       'pass' => array('id'),
       'id' => '[0-9]+'
   )
);
```